# how to get one record in a table into two records of a separate table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

According to the old database, I have a table called guardiant, it has a foreign key called db_id (which is from the student table). And the table structure is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `guardiant` (
  `db_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `fg_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fg_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fg_tel_work` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fg_mobile` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fg_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `fg_prof` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_address` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_tel_work` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_mobile` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_email` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `mg_prof` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `by` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`db_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

This table contains both records of mother and father (father being fg_ and mother being mg_). I need to migrate the data into another table which can only contain either a mother or a father. The structure is similar to this:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `fsms_parent_guardian` (
  `parent_guardian_id` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `address_1` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `address_2` varchar(200) default NULL,
  `date_of_birth` date default NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) default NULL,
  `education` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `email` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `first_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `middle_name` varchar(100) default NULL,
  `modified_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
  `modified_date` date NOT NULL,
  `nationality` varchar(20) default NULL,
  `profession` varchar(50) default NULL,
 PRIMARY KEY  (`parent_guardian_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

So one record in the old table should go into two records of the new table with separate ids. **Also primary keys from fsms_parent_guardian table and the student table should be mapped into a separated table.** Please tell me a feasible way to solve this.

Comment: What have you tried? This is pretty basic stuff so I'd at least expect a list of some of the things you've tried and example SQL code.

Comment: You might also want to include a gender field in your second table to make it easier to associate with each parent.

Comment: The problem I'm facing is getting one record and splitting them into two records. And also getting the two ids of the two records and map them to a single student_id in a separate table called student_parent. If its just one record i am able to do it. Also I am unable to change the structure of the DB. because its already designed by my superiors and i cant change it

Answer (score 0):

to copy the records, you will need tow querys, the first one selects fg records and inserts them in the new table, the second one selects the mg records and insert them again. Each record of fg and mg needs to be mapped to the student table with a foreign key (ID_student).